# Database joining table in geodjango

Tags: database, geodjango

I created a model class Parcel:

```
 from django.db import models
 from django.contrib.gis.db import models as gismodels

 class Parcel(gismodels.Model):
     new_pin = models.CharField(max_length=32)
     geometry = gismodels.PolygonField(srid=32651)
     objects = gismodels.GeoManager()


  def __unicode__(self):
      return self.new_pin`
```

Now, I want these model to have a joined query in other table(property), but these table(property) already existed in the database. Anybody knows how to implement it in python-geodjango?? Eventhough table(property) does not declared in my model.??How can I do it??

This is now the query I would like to display..
query in sql: (select t2.land_classification from table1 t1, table2 t2 where t1.new_pin = t2.new_pin group by t2.land_classification)

NOTE: Table 1 is the Parcel model above.
      Table 2 is the existed table in the database.

Comment: How many categories of the land classification are there?